# Best Python looping system for merging pandas DataFrame rows for export

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am a self-teaching data science student, currently doing my first big Python portfolio project in several steps, the first of which is using pandas to work with IMDb [Internet Movie Database]'s [rather oddly structured .tsv file](https://datasets.imdbws.com/)s in an effort to create a fully searchable big data repository of all IMDb data (the officially supported searches and even APIs like [OMDB (Open Movie Database)](https://www.omdbapi.com/) don't allow for the kinds of detailed queries I need to do for the larger project).

The structure of IMDb's public files is that they include all data on movies, TV shows, episodes, actors, directors, crew, the whole business, scattered rather haphazardly across seven massive tsv files. I've confirmed that pandas can, in fact, read in all of this data and that my computer's memory can handle it, but what I want to do is merge the seven tsv files into a single DataFrame object which can then be exported to (preferably) a SQL database or even a huge spreadsheet/another TSV file but larger.

Each *thing* in the database (movie, actor, individual TV episode) has a tconst row, which, in one file is identified as "titleId", a string. In every other file, this is identified as "tconst", also a string. I'm going to need to change titleId when I read that file into tconst; this is one of several challenges I haven't got to yet.

```
#set pandas formatting parameters
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 25)

#read in the data tables provided
showbiz_core = pd.read_table("name.basics.tsv",sep='\t')

#temporary hack - print the entire dataframe as test
print(showbiz_core)
```

This works, but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed next. I want to import each of the other tsv files to attempt to locally reconstruct the imdb database. This means that I don't want to have duplicate tconst strings, but rather to end up with new information about a tconst entry (like a film) appended to it as new columns.

Should I be looking to do a "for i in [new file]" type loop somehow? How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The IMdB files are actually highly structured.  Looping is always a bad structure for merging data

1. structure data sourcing - I used `wget` rather than manually sourcing
2. the files are large so work with a subset for modelling purpose.  I just have used popular movies and actors as driver
3. the CSV columns in the *tsv* files are actually sub-tables.  Treat them as such.  I build a reference entity *dmi* to do this
4. there are other associative relationships there as well *primaryProfession*, *genres*
5. finally join (merge) everything together from OMDB and IMdB.  Taken first rows where many items associate to a title

I have left data currently as *tsv* clearly it would be very simple to put into a database using `to_sql()` method.  Main point is sourcing and transformation.  aka ETL which has become an unfashionable term.  This can be further supplemented with web scraping.  I looked at [Box Office Mojo](https://www.boxofficemojo.com) however this would require `selenium` to scrape it as it's dynamic HTML

#### IMdB sourcing

```
import requests, json, re, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import wget,gzip
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

# find what IMdB has to give ...
resp = requests.get("https://datasets.imdbws.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode(), "html.parser")
files = {}
for f in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    if f["href"].endswith('gz'):
        u = urllib.parse.urlparse(f["href"])
        fn = Path().cwd().joinpath(u.path.strip("/"))
        files[Path(fn.stem).stem] = fn.name
        if not fn.is_file():
            wget.download(f["href"])
```

#### IMdB transform

set `alldata=True` on first run to prep data.  Second run false and you have a manageable subset

```
alldata = False
subsetdata = True

dfs={}

# work with a subset of data to speed up modelling and iterations.  Take a few major actors and titles
# as criteria to build a manageable representative set of data
l = ["Tom Hanks","Will Smith","Clint Eastwood","Leonardo DiCaprio","Johnny Depp","Meryl Streep","Bruce Willis"]
tm = {'tconst': ['tt0111161','tt0468569','tt1375666','tt0137523','tt0110912','tt0109830','tt0944947','tt0133093','tt0120737','tt0167260','tt0068646'],
 'averageRating': [9.3, 9.0, 8.8, 8.8, 8.9, 8.8, 9.3, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9.2],
 'numVotes': [2275837,2237966,1997918,1805137,1777920,1752954,1699318,1630083,1618100,1602417,1570167]}

# work with subset for modelling purpose
k = "name.basics"
if alldata:
    dfs[k] = pd.read_csv(gzip.open(files[k]), sep="\t").replace({"\\N":np.nan})
    if subsetdata:
        # manage down size of nmi
        dfs[k] = dfs[k].loc[(dfs[k]["primaryName"].isin(l)
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][0])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][1])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][2])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][3])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][4])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][5])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][6])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][7])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][8])
                            | dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains(tm["tconst"][9])
                            )
                            &dfs[k]["knownForTitles"].str.contains("tt")]
        dfs[k].to_csv(f"{files[k]}_subset.tsv", sep="\t", index=False)
else:
    dfs[k] = pd.read_csv(f"{files[k]}_subset.tsv", sep="\t")
dfs[k] = dfs[k].astype({c:"Int64" for c in dfs[k].columns}, errors="ignore")
# birth year is a lot but getting data issues...
# dfs[k] = dfs[k].dropna(subset=["primaryProfession","birthYear"])

# comma separated - not good for joins and merges. rename for consistency
dfs["nmi"] = (dfs["name.basics"].loc[:,["nconst","knownForTitles"]]
 .assign(knownForTitles=lambda x: x["knownForTitles"].str.split(","))
 .explode("knownForTitles")
).rename(columns={"knownForTitles":"tconst"}).drop_duplicates()
# already extracted known titles so can drop and de-dup - e.g. Tom Hanks
dfs[k] = dfs[k].drop(columns=["knownForTitles"]).drop_duplicates()

for k in [k for k in files.keys() if k not in ["name.basics","omdb.titles"]]:
    if alldata:
        dfs[k] = pd.read_csv(gzip.open(files[k]), sep="\t").replace({"\\N":np.nan})
        if k=="title.akas": dfs[k]=dfs[k].rename(columns={"titleId":"tconst"})
        # subset titles to those we have names
        if subsetdata:
            c = "tconst" if k!= "title.episode" else "parentTconst"
            try:
                (dfs[k].loc[dfs[k][c].isin(dfs["nmi"]["tconst"])]
                 .to_csv(f"{files[k]}_subset.tsv", sep="\t", index=False))
            except KeyError as e:
                print(k, dfs[k].columns, e)
    else:
        dfs[k] = pd.read_csv(f"{files[k]}_subset.tsv", sep="\t")
    dfs[k] = dfs[k].astype({c:"Int64" for c in dfs[k].columns}, errors="ignore")

dfs["name.and.titles"] = dfs["nmi"].merge(dfs["name.basics"], on="nconst").merge(dfs["title.basics"], on="tconst")
```

#### OMDB sourcing

```
omdbcols = ['Title', 'Year', 'Rated', 'Released', 'Runtime', 'Genre', 'Director', 'Writer', 'Actors', 'Plot', 'Language', 'Country', 'Awards', 'Poster', 'Ratings', 'Metascore', 'imdbRating', 'imdbVotes', 'imdbID', 'Type', 'DVD', 'BoxOffice', 'Production', 'Website', 'Response']
omdbk = "omdb.titles"
files[omdbk] = f"{omdbk}.tsz"
if not Path().cwd().joinpath(files[omdbk]).is_file():
    dfs[omdbk] = pd.DataFrame(columns=omdbcols)
else:
    dfs[omdbk] = pd.read_csv(files[omdbk], sep="\t", thousands=",")
    dfs[omdbk] = dfs[omdbk].astype({c:"Int64" for c in dfs[omdbk].columns}, errors="ignore")
    

k = "title.basics"
# limited to 1000 API calls a day, so only fetch if have not done already
for tconst in dfs[k].loc[~(dfs[k]["tconst"].isin(dfs[omdbk]["imdbID"]))]["tconst"].values:
    # tt0109830 movie   Forrest Gump
    # http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=xxx
    params={"apikey":apikey,"i":tconst,"plot":"full"}
    res = requests.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/", params=params)
    if res.status_code!=200:
        print("breached API limit")
        break
    else:
        dfs[omdbk] = pd.concat([dfs[omdbk], pd.json_normalize(res.json())])
    
dfs[omdbk].to_csv(files[omdbk], index=False, sep="\t")
```

#### sample analysis

```
# The Dark Knight   tt0468569   
# Game of Throne tt0944947
# for demo purpose - just pick first association when there are many
mask = dfs[omdbk]["imdbID"].isin(["tt0468569","tt0944947"])
demo = (dfs[omdbk].loc[mask]
 .rename(columns={c:f"OMDB{c}" for c in dfs[omdbk].columns})
 .rename(columns={"OMDBimdbID":"tconst"})
 .merge(dfs["title.basics"], on="tconst")
 .merge(dfs["title.ratings"], on="tconst")
 .merge(dfs["title.akas"].groupby("tconst", as_index=False).first(), on="tconst")
 .merge(dfs["title.crew"].groupby("tconst", as_index=False).first(), on="tconst")
 .merge(dfs["title.principals"].groupby("tconst", as_index=False).first(), on="tconst")
 .merge(dfs["title.episode"].groupby("parentTconst", as_index=False).first(), 
        left_on="tconst", right_on="parentTconst", how="left", suffixes=("","_ep"))
 .merge(dfs["nmi"]
        .merge(dfs["name.basics"], on="nconst")
        .groupby(["tconst"], as_index=False).first(), on="tconst", suffixes=("","_name")) 

).T
```

#### output

```
                                                                                                                                                                        0                                                                                                                                                                                              1
OMDBTitle                                                                                                                                                 The Dark Knight                                                                                                                                                                                Game of Thrones
OMDBYear                                                                                                                                                             2008                                                                                                                                                                                      2011–2019
OMDBRated                                                                                                                                                           PG-13                                                                                                                                                                                          TV-MA
OMDBReleased                                                                                                                                                  18 Jul 2008                                                                                                                                                                                    17 Apr 2011
OMDBRuntime                                                                                                                                                       152 min                                                                                                                                                                                         57 min
OMDBGenre                                                                                                                                  Action, Crime, Drama, Thriller                                                                                                                                                     Action, Adventure, Drama, Fantasy, Romance
OMDBDirector                                                                                                                                            Christopher Nolan                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN
OMDBWriter                          Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters)                                                                                                                                                                      David Benioff, D.B. Weiss
OMDBActors                                                                                                     Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine                                                                                                                                      Peter Dinklage, Lena Headey, Emilia Clarke, Kit Harington
OMDBLanguage                                                                                                                                            English, Mandarin                                                                                                                                                                                        English
OMDBCountry                                                                                                                                                       USA, UK                                                                                                                                                                                        USA, UK
OMDBAwards                                                                                                              Won 2 Oscars. Another 153 wins & 159 nominations.                                                                                                                                        Won 1 Golden Globe. Another 374 wins & 602 nominations.
OMDBPoster                                                             https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg                                                             https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRiNDQwYzAtMzVlZS00NTI5LWJjYjUtMzkwNTUzMWMxZTllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDIzMzcwNjc@._V1_SX300.jpg
OMDBRatings        [{'Source': 'Internet Movie Database', 'Value': '9.0/10'}, {'Source': 'Rotten Tomatoes', 'Value': '94%'}, {'Source': 'Metacritic', 'Value': '84/100'}]                                                                                                                                     [{'Source': 'Internet Movie Database', 'Value': '9.3/10'}]
OMDBMetascore                                                                                                                                                          84                                                                                                                                                                                           <NA>
OMDBimdbRating                                                                                                                                                          9                                                                                                                                                                                            9.3
OMDBimdbVotes                                                                                                                                                     2234169                                                                                                                                                                                        1679892
tconst                                                                                                                                                          tt0468569                                                                                                                                                                                      tt0944947
OMDBType                                                                                                                                                            movie                                                                                                                                                                                         series
OMDBDVD                                                                                                                                                       09 Dec 2008                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN
OMDBBoxOffice                                                                                                                                                $533,316,061                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN
OMDBProduction                                                                                                                            Warner Bros. Pictures/Legendary                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN
OMDBWebsite                                                                                                                                                          <NA>                                                                                                                                                                                           <NA>
OMDBResponse                                                                                                                                                            1                                                                                                                                                                                              1
OMDBtotalSeasons                                                                                                                                                     <NA>                                                                                                                                                                                              8
titleType                                                                                                                                                           movie                                                                                                                                                                                       tvSeries
primaryTitle                                                                                                                                              The Dark Knight                                                                                                                                                                                Game of Thrones
originalTitle                                                                                                                                             The Dark Knight                                                                                                                                                                                Game of Thrones
isAdult                                                                                                                                                                 0                                                                                                                                                                                              0
startYear                                                                                                                                                            2008                                                                                                                                                                                           2011
endYear                                                                                                                                                              <NA>                                                                                                                                                                                           2019
runtimeMinutes                                                                                                                                                        152                                                                                                                                                                                             57
genres                                                                                                                                                 Action,Crime,Drama                                                                                                                                                                         Action,Adventure,Drama
averageRating                                                                                                                                                           9                                                                                                                                                                                            9.3
numVotes                                                                                                                                                          2237966                                                                                                                                                                                        1699318
ordering_x                                                                                                                                                             10                                                                                                                                                                                             10
title                                                                                                                                                     The Dark Knight                                                                                                                                                                                  Taht Oyunları
region                                                                                                                                                                 GB                                                                                                                                                                                             TR
language                                                                                                                                                               en                                                                                                                                                                                             tr
types                                                                                                                                                         imdbDisplay                                                                                                                                                                                    imdbDisplay
attributes                                                                                                                                             fake working title                                                                                                                                                                                  literal title
isOriginalTitle                                                                                                                                                         0                                                                                                                                                                                              0
directors                                                                                                                                                       nm0634240  nm0851930,nm0551076,nm0533713,nm0336241,nm1888967,nm1047532,nm0764601,nm0007008,nm0617042,nm0787687,nm0687964,nm0070474,nm1125275,nm0638354,nm0002399,nm0806252,nm0755261,nm0887700,nm0590889
writers                                                                                                                           nm0634300,nm0634240,nm0333060,nm0004170                                                                                                      nm1125275,nm0552333,nm1888967,nm4984276,nm2643685,nm7260047,nm2977599,nm0961827,nm0260870
ordering_y                                                                                                                                                             10                                                                                                                                                                                             10
nconst                                                                                                                                                          nm0746273                                                                                                                                                                                      nm0322513
category                                                                                                                                                         producer                                                                                                                                                                                          actor
job                                                                                                                                                              producer                                                                                                                                                                                        creator
characters                                                                                                                                                ["Bruce Wayne"]                                                                                                                                                                              ["Jorah Mormont"]
parentTconst                                                                                                                                                          NaN                                                                                                                                                                                      tt0944947
tconst_ep                                                                                                                                                             NaN                                                                                                                                                                                      tt1480055
seasonNumber                                                                                                                                                         <NA>                                                                                                                                                                                              1
episodeNumber                                                                                                                                                        <NA>                                                                                                                                                                                              1
nconst_name                                                                                                                                                     nm0000198                                                                                                                                                                                      nm0000293
primaryName                                                                                                                                                   Gary Oldman                                                                                                                                                                                      Sean Bean
birthYear                                                                                                                                                            1958                                                                                                                                                                                           1959
deathYear                                                                                                                                                            1998                                                                                                                                                                                           2020
primaryProfession                                                                                                                               actor,soundtrack,producer                                                                                                                                                            actor,producer,animation_department
```

Comment: Here's the problem - and I appreciate the answer, but the thing is, I'm trying to solve a very specific problem, not take a random sample at this time. I need to be able to query the database with parameters that IMDb itself doesn't allow - for instance searching by the film's box office returns rather than by a title. I have to make my own copy of the dataset for that, even OMDB won't allow such queries, and I need all movies (from a certain time period) not just a random sample. I didn't get into that because I figured I'd jump through those hoops once I got the data integrated.

Comment: absolutely understand - however you have to get you data sourcing and normalisation of IMdB data first then supplement with additional sources second.  do you have a second source that you are trying to merge?  I can demonstrate what I mean

Comment: Hey I know you don't like my answer - I'm still working on this dataset.  There are issues with it.  IMdB data files do not associate *Will Smith* with *Bad Boys for Life*.  Just shows need to work with manageable subsets to check data represents what you think. Basics for an old school data person like me or new school data scientist ;-)

Comment: got caught up in this as a side project today as I've been intending to build something source and structure,  Hopefully update helps.   There is some box office data on OMDB,  not much

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed all of this. I don't not like your answer, I'm just a novice and also got caught up in a separate project!